# JAVA(TM) platform SE binary has stopped working while dealing with jUSB program

Tags: java, jusb

I have imported the usb package from JAVA USB in eclipse. 
I have added the jusb.dll in system32 folder.
I am using the windows 7 and JDK 7.
When I run the RunUSBControllerTest.java through eclipse I got the
error

> JAVA(TM) platform SE binary has stopped working

I have updated JDK 7 update 10. Please suggest me some solutions

These are the error details

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: javaw.exe
  Application Version:  7.0.100.18
  Application Timestamp:    50b6401f
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_9451
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdadb
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 000c283b
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 9451
  Additional Information 2: 945177d4dcd25bd15a24a1ac55a01ff1
  Additional Information 3: 1b4c
  Additional Information 4: 1b4c3e808b9e543d0671ecf153713e18
```

Comment: This could be a bug in the jusb.dll native library.